# Storage facade get method in returns File not found at path while file exists - Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, storage

I have added a local disk to my filesystems config

```
 'customDisk' => 
[
 'driver' => 'local',
 'root' => 'D:\RandomFolder',
],
```

In my DB Seeder I have the following line

```php
$file = Storage::disk('customDisk')->get($filename);
```

and I get the following error - File not found at path: path/name.

The thing is that the file does exist and I can't understand why this throws an error.

I am aware that I can use File:: facade, but I'm having other concerns about it and thus I'd rather not use it.

Comment: Probably `$filename` returns just the name of the file, not an additional path if it has it (for ex. `product/filename`). Use the `dd($filename)` and paste your output in question,

Comment: It does return folder Name/filename and later on I am using json_decode( $file, true ); which works fine for other files.

Comment: Can you do `dd(Storage::disk('customDisk')->get($filename))` and see if the path is actually correct?

Comment: $filename actually returns the contents of the file which later on I decode with json_decode.

Answer (score 0):

From your previous comment, I can see the problem now. You say your files returns content of the file, which probably contains size, mimeType, path and so on. So, you either have to read only path of that variable, or decode it before you use it in storage:

```
Storage::disk('customDisk')->get($filename->path)
```

or:

```
$file = json_decode($filename); 
$path = $file->path;
Storage::disk('customDisk')->get($path);
```

Didn't test it, but this should give you desired output.

Comment: Actually I just managed to fix it - the problem was with the order of the operations which I had wrong before. As the error was given for images which I don't json_decode after, I just placed the $file = Storage::disk('customDisk')->get($filename); after I check the file and it is json file. All works good now.

Comment: Good to hear, share your solution, might help others in future.